# requirejs - define global variable as amd module

Tags: requirejs, amd, js-amd

I wrote a requirejs app and it will be included in various environments, some of them will already provide some javascript frameworks, that i would like to reuse insteadof the provided amd modules i bring along.

I am speaking about jquery and Foundation. Some of my app-scripts make use of those frameworks themselves and i would like to do something like the following example, but i cant figure out, if this can even be done with requirejs and if yes - how...

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "window.$",
        "foundation": "window.Foundation",
        "foundation.module": "window.Foundation.Module"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "window.$"
        },
        "foundation": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "window.Foundation"
        }
    }
});
```

Can i achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a proxy module. As the Foundation and jQuery is already loaded, before the RequireJS I assume.

It is quiet simple, just define a module which will return a global variable and that's all, here, take a look at jQuery example:

```javascript
define('jquery', function () {
  return window.$;
});
```

No config needed for that. You can remove the paths and the shims as they are no needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just did not find the time until today to test your solution. Works perfectly.